GitHub Actions: find command not working with wildcards
As part of our workflow, we have a dot-upload.sh script that has the find command in it. The relative path to the downloaded files is passed as argument to the script:
steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v4

  - name: Download API unit test results
    uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
    with:
      name: unit-test-results-api
      path: test-results/unit-test-results-api/

  - name: Where Am I
    run: pwd

  - name: Upload API unit test results to DoT
    run: ./scripts/dot-upload.sh test-results/unit-test-results-api/test-results.xml
    shell: bash

  - name: Download UI unit test results
    uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
    with:
      name: unit-test-results-ui
      path: test-results/unit-test-results-ui/

  - name: Where Am I
    run: pwd

  - name: Upload UI unit test results to DoT
    run: ./scripts/dot-upload.sh test-results/unit-test-results-ui/**/*.xml
    shell: bash

When the relative path including the file name is passed, the find command works and returns the matching file:

However, when wildcards /**/ are used to return files in nested dirs, the find command says No such file or directory:


surely that intrepreter/parser of your yaml file is not a shell and has own globbing rules

Remove quotes from the argument of find and try again.

Hi @Azeem , there is only 1 line in the .sh file that uses find and it looks like this FILE_NAMES=$(find $1). I don't see quotes around the param. In the YML where we call the script, there is also no quotes. Is GitHub Actions automatically adding quotes? Hosted agent is ubuntu-latest.

Shell globbing has a lot of limits. If you already use find, then it's a bit odd to do part of its job by shell. For FILE_NAMES=$(find $1) you can change that to FILE_NAMES="$(find "$1" -name "*.$2")" and call your script with two arguments (search-dir and file-extension) like ./scripts/dot-upload.sh test-results/unit-test-results-ui xml
